# PHP does not resolve .local dns names with gethostbyname

Tags: php, dns

I have werid problem with name resolution. I am trying to connect to active directory server. I can successfully get the ldap server address from the SRV recodrs. Then I try to resolve the dns names to IP addresses and it fails:

```
<?php
echo 'example.com.:' . PHP_EOL;
echo gethostbyname('example.com.');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'dc1.veracomp.local.:' . PHP_EOL;
echo gethostbyname('dc1.my-company.local.');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'nslookup  dc1.my-company.local.:' . PHP_EOL;
echo `nslookup dc1.my-company.local.`;
```

The example.com is resolved correctly, then the `gethostbyname('dc1.my-company.local.')` fails after a few seconds returning `dc1.my-company.local.` instead of the IP address. Still the same PHP script can call nslookup which correctly resolves the domain name...:

```
example.com.:
93.184.216.119
dc1.my-company.local.:
dc1.my-company.local.
nslookup  dc1.my-company.local.:
Server:         xxx.xxx.254.117
Address:        xxx.xxx.254.117#53

Name:   dc1.my-company.local
Address: 192.168.12.21
```

**What is wrong here?**

EDIT:
I am asking for name resolution beacuse the real problem i have is that I **can** connect to `ldap://192.168.12.21` or to `ldap://dc1.my-company.pl`, but I **cannot** connect to `ldap://dc1.my-company.local`.

Unfortunatelly the SRV records for _ldap._tcp.my-company.pl returns only local addresses. I do not want to hardcode the .pl address. And I do not understand why I have to manually resolve the local addresses before passing them to Zend_Ldap as a `host` option.

Comment: Another guess is that PHP built-in function considers `.local` as not-valid domain - hence the error.

Comment: Have fun reading php C sources and using wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid its use in production. DNS Resolution may take from 0.5 to 4 seconds, and during this time your script is NOT being executed.

I use this one; this will be faster and more efficient:

```
<?php
function getAddrByHost($hosts, $timeout = 3) {
  $returnString = '';
  foreach ($hosts as $host) {
    $query = `nslookup -timeout=$timeout -retry=1 $host`;
    if (preg_match('/\nAddress: (.*)\n/', $query, $matches))
      $returnString .= trim($matches[1]) . '<br>';
    $returnString .= $host . '<br>';
  }
  return $returnString;

}

$hostArray[] = 'www.example.com';
$hostArray[] = 'dc1.my-company.local';

$returnString = getAddrByHost($hostArray);
echo $returnString;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I might, and probably will use your solution, but I would still like to know why PHP is not able to resolve a correct dns domain name from local scope.